# What is the simplest of checking first and last character of a string in php

Tags: php, string

What is the simplest way of checking whether the first letter of a string `$str` is `'a'` and the last letter is `'a'` too?

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->start()`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L176) and [`s($str)->end()`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L192) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
if($str[0] == 'a' && $str[strlen($str) - 1] == 'a') {
    //do whatever you wanted
}
```

Comment: With PHP 7.1 you can even do it like this: `if ($str[0] === 'a' && $str[-1] === 'a') { /* do stuff */ }`

Comment: Be wary if the string you're checking either has zero length or not a string (e.g. false), as this will generate a NOTICE. Either do some type and length checks first, or use `substr` instead, which returns an empty string.

Answer (score 8):

```
if(substr($str, 0,1) == "a" && substr( $str,-1) == "a")
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: North Creative: You meant `substr($str,`, not `$str.substr(`.

Answer (score 2):

Or use substr to get the last character:

```
if($str[0] == 'a' && substr($str,-1) == 'a') {
    //do whatever you wanted
}
```